# Custom sort implementation causes link errors

Tags: c++, sorting, initialization

I want to sort some Bridge data so that N (for No Trumps) appears after S (for Spades).  The following works if I keep all the code in one file

```
   class Bridge_lt_str : public std::binary_function<std::string, std::string, bool>
    {
    public:
        struct lt_char
        {
            const char *tab;
        };

        char tab[CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN + 1];

        Bridge_lt_str(const std::locale& L = std::locale::classic())
        {
            const std::ctype<char>& ct = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(L);
            for (int i = CHAR_MIN; i <= CHAR_MAX; ++i)  // cast for char.
                tab[i - CHAR_MIN] = static_cast<char>(i); // (char)i 

            //Only concerned with ordering C, D, H, S, N=NT.
            tab['N' - CHAR_MIN] = tab['Z' - CHAR_MIN];
            ct.toupper(tab, tab + CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN + 1);
        }
    };

Bridge_lt_str lt_str;


bool isDenomLess(std::string& lhs, std::string& rhs)
    {//NT is the highest denomination.  Otherwise, everything sorts normally.
        if (lhs[0] == rhs[0]) return lt_str.tab[lhs[1] - CHAR_MIN] < lt_str.tab[rhs[1] - CHAR_MIN];
        return lhs[0] < rhs[0];
    }
```

I'd like to factor all this out into a separate include files 
and just call the isDenomLess sort function from the main code e.g.

```
std::sort(tks.begin(), tks.end(), &isDenomLess);
```

This works fine for some other sort functions e.g.

```
sort(v_keys.begin(), v_keys.end(), order_by_score_freq);
```

and I've inlined the functions in a separate header file

```
inline bool order_by_score_freq(const Result & r1, const Result & r2);
inline bool isDenomLess(std::string& lhs, std::string& rhs);
```

but, presumably because of the tab array initialization, anything I've tried gives a link error

```
LNK2005: "class Bridge_lt_str lt_str" (?lt_str@@3VBridge_lt_str@@A) already defined in Bridge.obj
```

Any help on a suitable include structure much appreciated!

Comment: Are you defining implementations in your header file? That's a big "no".

Comment: Move the global definitions to a separate translation unit or mark them `inline`. @tadman _"That's a big "no". "_ Not _per se_.

Comment: @user0042 If you put non-`inline` implementations in your header files you're asking for problems like this. Marking these `inline` is completely inappropriate. This is not performance sensitive code, it can live where it's supposed to live: a `.cpp` implementation file.

Comment: @tadman The compiler (linker) would decide to actually inline that code or not anyways. It doesn't make a difference IMO.

Comment: I'd put the code in the cpp file if only to avoid violating [the Law of Least Surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: @user0042 I'm with user4581301 here: Putting code in strange places is really a bad idea. It's like organizing your kitchen by storing cutlery in a bucket under the sink and perishable food in the broom closet. You can do it, but it's annoying to someone else trying to work in your kitchen.

Comment: @tadman Well, I'm not really a friend of that kind of code organization, but doing that _right_ is completely legal, and shouldn't do any harm performance wise or such.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the line:

```
Bridge_lt_str lt_str;
```

Change that to:

```
extern Bridge_lt_str lt_str;
```

And then in one of your .cpp files have:

```
Bridge_lt_str lt_str;
```

Having the code (in the header is fine, so long as the definitions are inside the class body or they are declared with the 'inline' specifier.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean this up and split it out into separate files which helps from an organizational perspective.

In your `.h` header file you try and stay focused on laying out the big picture:

```
class Bridge_lt_str : public std::binary_function<std::string, std::string, bool>
{
public:
    struct lt_char
    {
        const char *tab;
    };

    Bridge_lt_str(const std::locale& L = std::locale::classic());

    char tab[CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN + 1];
};

bool isDenomLess(std::string& lhs, std::string& rhs);
```

It's worth noting that from an object-oriented design perspective you want to avoid exposing internals that should not be accessed by other code. Keep these `private` or `protected` depending on how you want to lock down access.

Then in your `bridge_lt_str.cpp` implementation file you define how these work:

```
Bridge_lt_str::Bridge_lt_str(const std::locale& L)
{
    const std::ctype<char>& ct = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(L);
    for (int i = CHAR_MIN; i <= CHAR_MAX; ++i)
        tab[i - CHAR_MIN] = static_cast<char>(i);

    //Only concerned with ordering C, D, H, S, N=NT.
    tab['N' - CHAR_MIN] = tab['Z' - CHAR_MIN];
    ct.toupper(tab, tab + CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN + 1);
}

bool isDenomLess(std::string& lhs, std::string& rhs)
{
    if (lhs[0] == rhs[0])
        return lt_str.tab[lhs[1] - CHAR_MIN] < lt_str.tab[rhs[1] - CHAR_MIN];

    return lhs[0] < rhs[0];
}
```

Do try and flag things as `const` in your arguments if you're not intending to change them. The `isDenomLess` function doesn't modify those strings, so `const std::string&` is the appropriate type for those arguments. Leaving out `const` usually communicates an intent to modify them. It can also annoy those trying to use your function when all they have is a `const` string and for no reason you need one that's non-`const`.

In some other file like `main.cpp` you can then use your class:

```
int main() {
    Bridge_lt_str lt_str;

    return 0;
}
```

You'll need to link both the compiler output from `main.cpp` (e.g. `main.o`) and that from the other one (e.g. `bridge_lt_str.o`) together. This is standard in any non-trivial C++ program so you should have a `Makefile` or equivalent to do that for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks - that seems a very clean structure.  I think the header fucntion needs to have the default value removed i.e.  Bridge_lt_str(const std::locale& ); But, once that's done, it compiles and should run (I'll test later on).  Visual Studio went through a phase of telling me that the recompiled file was out of date but it seems to have gotten over that (I'm always suspicious of problems that just go away!)

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio you shouldn't have to fuss too much with linking so you should be on the right track now by splitting things up cleanly. You're probably right about the default value so I've removed it from here.